# Cannot send a content-body with this verb-type

Tags: c#, ftp

```
    FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://www.MySite.com/public_html/Text.txt");
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;

    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(" ", " ");

    StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "/Text.txt");
    byte[] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
    sourceStream.Close();
    request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;

    Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
    requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
    requestStream.Close();

    FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    response.Close();
```

Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream(); is giving me the error "Cannot send a content-body with this verb-type.".

Any help on how to fix this would be great.

Comment: have you tried request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile ...

Answer (score 2):

You have told it to use DownloadFile, which is the FTP RETR method - and which does not take a body - in the same way that HTTP GET does not take a body. Specify UploadFile (FTP STOR) or similar if you want to send a body; or - don't send a body.